# What is the prefered way in using the parallel collections in Scala?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, language-design, scala-collections

At first I assumed that every collection class would receive an additional `par` method which would convert the collection to a fitting parallel data structure (like `map` returns the best collection for the element type in Scala 2.8).

Now it seems that some collection classes support a `par` method (e. g. Array) but others have `toParSeq`, `toParIterable` methods (e. g. List). This is a bit weird, since Array isn't used or recommended that often.

What is the reason for that? Wouldn't it be better to just have a `par` available on all collection classes doing the "right thing"?

If I have data which might be processed in parallel, what types should I use? The traits in `scala.collection` or the type of the implementation directly?

Or should I prefer `Arrays` now, because they seem to be cheaper to parallelize?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lists aren't that well suited for parallel processing.  The reason is that to get to the end of the list, you have to walk through every single element.  Thus, you may as well just treat the list as an iterator, and thus may as well just use something more generic like `toParIterable`.

Any collection that has a fast index is a good candidate for parallel processing.  This includes anything implementing `LinearSeqOptimized`, plus trees and hash tables.  `Array` has as fast of an index as you can get, so it's a fairly natural choice.  You can also use things like `ArrayBuffer` (which has a `par` method returning a `ParArray`).

Comment: This seems kind of like how there's only a `.sorted` on `SeqLike`, so you have to do `items.toSeq.sorted` instead of just `items.sorted`. So why have all the `.toParIterable` etc. methods, instead of just telling people to do `items.toArray.par` when `items` isn't parallelizable?

Comment: @Steve - There is some chance that the `toParIterable` methods don't have to make a copy of the underlying data.  So even though they're slow, they could occasionally be a good compromise (e.g. when traversing the list or whatnot is fast compared to the computation on each element of the list).